# Windows 7 and cd to symbolic links

Tags: windows, command-line

So I have created a bunch of symbolic links to top of source code tree, data directories, etc

How do I, from command line, cd to these links?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you sure you actually created symbolic links, or did you create a Windows Shortcut? Those are not links, and don't work as such. Actual symbolic links behave like other directories, so if you are unable to `cd` into it, either you a) don't have permissions to enter the target directory, b) the symlink doesn't point to a valid directory, or c) it's actually not a symlink.

(If you want to create NTFS symlinks, use the MKLINK command)

---

As a parable, imagine a river and its tributaries: all those rivers flow into the large river; that is the directory structure; riverside towns are files. Now, a Windows Shortcut is just a sign on the riverbank: "it's not here, you need to go back down to Mississippi and then up Ohio, it is five miles upstream, on the left bank" - but you need to read English to understand it (have a program which handles this for you, e.g. Explorer.exe). A symlink is like a water canal: if you follow it, it will actually take you someplace else, no matter whether you can read English or not (no matter what program you use).

Comment: same thing as downloads folder shortcut? I thought that is the way you create a symbolic link in Windows 7

Comment: **shortcut != symbolic link** : "shortcuts" are just regular files with content "see that other thing over there", and they are handled by the shell (Explorer.exe, pretty much a normal program). "symbolic links" are special data structures in the NTFS structure, which make a directory accessible from an alternate location; they are handled internally, rather deep in the OS.

Comment: No; shortcuts are not symlinks.

Comment: @reza: As to "how to create symbolic links in Windows", see that link I posted.

Comment: @reza: As you are using Windows 7, it's the `mklink` command which you need to use, and not `junction` as mentioned in the answer, which is is for 2000/XP/2003.  `mklink` can be used to make junctions as well as symbolic links.

Comment: @paradroid: `junction` still works, even in Win10 ;)

Comment: @Piskvor Yeah sure, but there is no point in using it, as it cannot make symbolic links, so has less functionality than `mklink`, which is installed by default.

Comment: Aha! I didn't know that one comes preinstalled. Then it doesn't make sense to also install junction.exe . Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

Symbolic links are normal directories.
You can CD into them just like any other directory.

Comment: I have a link called: code

Comment: I have a link called: code, you are saying just type cd code. If that is what you are saying, it is not working.

Comment: Why not? What happens?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't talking about shortcuts?

Comment: the error is the same as any non existent path. System can not find the path specified is the error

Answer (score 0):

Example: Target folder is d:\code\ , I made a **shortcut** (rightclick-drag-drop) to it in C:\

see snapshot:
[image]

The  'shortcut' is an .lnk file which has the target path (*D:\code*)and a bunch of other junk in it ie. computer name (*kandalf*) and god knows what else.

You could parse the .lnk file and use the path inside it.
Google for 'parse .lnk file ' (in C/VB/Whatever you preffer) or '.lnk file format'

Too much trouble? why not use full paths in your config file/whatever it is you're doing? ;)

As a last resort I'd go for NTFS Junctions... Last resort because, the windows file manager is stupid, ie. when you delete a junction it doesn't just delete the junction; it deletes the junction AND the target folder and all it's files! Now think of that junction sitting under a deep directory structure in an obscure folder that you later want to delete -- yup you guessed it!

Comment: @DMB: Explorer in Vista and newer are junction-aware.  Deleting a junction will only delete the junction itself, not the target.